# SaxParser concatenation prob

Tags: java, sax, saxparser

I have an xml file that reads like

```
<Event Id="258" Key="123456">
<SubEvent Id="1">
Microsoft will begin selling its &quot;Kinect&quot; full-body motion-sensing game system from November 4, while Sony launched its &quot;Move&quot; motion-controlled gaming system on September 15.  
</SubEvent>
</Event>
```

Part of the parser handler

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) {
         scored = false;
         event = true;
                   if (//my condition){
                        scored = true; 
                   }
                   if (scored){
                           sb= new StringBuffer();
     }
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (event) {
        event = false;
    }

    if (subevent) {
                    if (scored){
                            sb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
                    }
        subevent = false;

    }
}
```

But this only returns " Microsoft will begin selling its "

I read that the parser might do multiple characters calls.
How do I concatenate the different calls together? Can you please explain the logic flow?

Additional info:
I did a print all of the elements, it appears that the rest of the sentence is not being called, why??

```
 Start Element :Event
 Start Element :SubEvent
 SubEvent: 
 Microsoft will begin selling its 
 End Element :SubEvent
 End Element :Event
 Start Element :Event
 Start Element :SubEvent
 SubEvent: 
 Nintendo will sell a new version of its DS handheld device that can play games and show movies in 3D without glasses sometime before March 2011. 
 End Element :SubEvent
 End Element :Event
```

Answer (score 0):

The `characters(char ch[], int start, int length)` method does not read full lines, you should store the characters in a `StringBuffer` and use it in the `endElement` method.

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
{

     if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) 
     {
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
     }
     sb = new StringBuffer();
}
```

Comment: Please see my additional info. Sax isnt printing the other parts of the line, either, but jumps to the next event immediately

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
    String qName) throws SAXException {
         if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) {
                scored = false;
            }
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("subevent")){
                subevent=false;
            }
}
```